# How come JQuery doesn't pass JSLint?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What good is JSLint if jQuery fails the validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505251/what-good-is-jslint-if-jquery-fails-the-validation)

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js

Go to there and paste it in www.jslint.com

Isn't Jquery supposed to be valid....

Comment: This was asked before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505251/what-good-is-jslint-if-jquery-fails-the-validation

Comment: JSLint is not about validity. It's more about coding conventions. That's my point of view.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

It's far too much work to comply with it *AND* be cross-browser compliant. JSLint is useful but its only a generic parser. jQuery has good reasons to throw errors in it.

Sometimes you just need simple dirty hacks to get code working in non-compliant browsers.

let's look at them one by one :

> Problem at line 231 character 20:
> Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
>
> return num == null ?

Here jQuery uses `==` on `null` to check for both `undefined` and `null`. Since jQuery is used as an external library it can't guarantee whether the input we pass to functions will be `undefined` or `null`. It is safer for it check for both.

Doing `num === undefined || num === null` to satisfy JSLint is ridiculous.

> Problem at line 446 character 29:
> Expected a conditional expression and
> instead saw an assignment.
>
> while ( (fn = ready[ i++ ]) ) {

Here JSLint complains about assignment instead of equals check. The reason JSLint throws this error is because its common to type `=` instead of `==` by mistake. Assigning in this while loop is done on purpose to make the code neater.

> Problem at line 550 character 9: Empty
> block.
>
> var key; for ( key in obj ) {}
> return key === undefined ||
> hasOwn.call( obj, key );

JSLint complains about an empty for block. This here has been done on purpose because we don't want to do anything with `key` instead we want to enumerate over all the keys and only care about the last one.

> Problem at line 554 character 15: Move
> 'var' declarations to the top of the
> function.
>
> for ( var name in obj ) {

JSLint insists on having variables declaration at the top of functions. This is a bit silly and can be ignored if you want to. It's a matter of style.

And then the parser crashes. Let me remove some of the code crashing it and see if I can find more complaints.

> Problem at line 792 character 42: The
> '&&' subexpression should be wrapped
> in parens.
>
> ua.indexOf("compatible") < 0 &&
> rmozilla.exec( ua ) ||

I actually agree with this one `(ua.indexO("compatile") < 0) &&` is better.

> Problem at line 872 character 3: Move
> the invocation into the parens that
> contain the function.
>
> })();

For closures like:

```
(function() {
  
})();
//}());
```

JSLint prefers to see the function invocation in the brackets as a matter of style. I also agree with this one but it really doesn't matter at all.

> Problem at line 972 character 13: 'e'
> is already defined.
>
> } catch(e) {

Parser is complaining about the reuse of variable `e` In this case we know that `e` will only be used locally in that catch block so it doesn't matter if we alter it outside the catch block. Here I prefer the readability of re-using the variable name `e`

> Problem at line 1097 character 21:
> Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
>
> elem = elem == window ?

Ok, you caught me on this one. I'm stumped as to why jQuery doesn't use `===` on `window`

> Problem at line 1621 character 24:
> Expected an assignment or function
> call and instead saw an expression.
>
> parent.selectedIndex;

```
// Safari mis-reports the default selected property of an option
// Accessing the parent's selectedIndex property fixes it
if ( name === "selected" && !jQuery.support.optSelected ) {
    var parent = elem.parentNode;
if ( parent ) {
    parent.selectedIndex;
```

Here's one of those cross-browser compliancy bugs that can be fixed but causes bad `code`

> Problem at line 977 character 17:
> Missing 'break' after 'case'.
>
> case "last":

JSLint says you should always break after your cases. It's perfectly valid to drop through after a case. In most cases you forgot to `break` but here this is intentional.

> Problem at line 1099 character 77:
> Expected an assignment or function
> call and instead saw an expression.
>
> Array.prototype.slice.call(
> document.documentElement.childNodes, 0
> )[0].node...

```
// Perform a simple check to determine if the browser is capable of
// converting a NodeList to an array using builtin methods.
// Also verifies that the returned array holds DOM nodes
// (which is not the case in the Blackberry browser)
try {
    Array.prototype.slice.call( document.documentElement.childNodes, 0 )[0].nodeType;
```

The source here speaks for itself. It's a weird statement but if accessing it like this throws an error then it can be caught. It's still valid just JSLint tells you "did you really mean to do this?"

> Problem at line 2377 character 15: Bad
> for in variable 'name'.
>
> for ( name in options ) {

Here JSLint complains about the use of `name` which can conflict with `window.name` in global scope. It's a "not quite reserved future keyword but still should be avoided". Were in a closure so it's safe.

> Problem at line 2486 character 29: Too
> many errors. (60% scanned).

JSLint's internal stack can't handle it. I'm going to stop now.

I think the point is illustrated.

JSLint has a lot of "Are you sure you want to do this" and we're telling it yes we want to do this. It might look like a mistake but it's not.

Comment: I disagree that it's evil; jslint is useful, you just have remember that the rules it follows are guidelines, to know what the errors and warnings mean and when you can ignore it.

Comment: @ElYobo your right. I was a bit harsh on JSLint.

Comment: Does that mean that `(null == undefined) === true` in every browser?

Comment: That is an incredibly detailed breakdown, +1 :D

Comment: Checking for `undefined` is even worse in the cases where `undefined` has been given a different value. Not a problem one would normally deal with when writing code that uses a library, but people designing libraries like jQuery assume the worst, and the only safe way to get the value of `undefined` is to compare your variable with `void 0` which can be even more confusing and make the code look even more like vomit.

Comment: One reason === doesn't work for window is that IE fails it-try to alert(window===top) and alert(window==top) in a top level window

Comment: @kennebec then answer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847024/question-about-jquery-source-on-window)

Comment: I know I'm behind the times but..."Doing num === undefined || num === null to satisfy JSLint is ridiculous." I think there are other reasons to do this than to just satisfy JSLint. The equality operator can be confusing and I think being more explicit makes code more readable. In my experience newer developers never realize undefined == null.

Answer (score 6):

The rules that jslint uses are *guidelines*, not unbreakable rules.  There are many reasons you might want to disregard some of them.

There are quite a few [detailed considerations of jslint rules](http://outofhanwell.wordpress.com/2006/06/05/jslint-considered-harmful/) out there; many people disagree with it.

Personally, I like it, but use the comments at the top of each JS file to switch on and off various warnings when I know that what I'm doing is appropriate.  We then run jslint against all of our JS as part of the CI tests and it catches a few trivial mistakes now and then without generally bothering us.

Comment: even with the various settings on and off there are still some things which JSLint throws errors on but are things you actually want to do. You don't have enough control over JSLint.

Comment: I added an extra flag to our tests to just skip jslint entirely on the components that I wanted to do things that it really doesn't like :)  I found that, for my tastes anyway, the minor overhead of complying with jslint is worth it for the things it catches and for enforcing a consistent style in the same way that phpcs does for our server side code

Comment: Belated update: [jshint](http://jshint.com/) offers similar checks with much more flexibility.