# Question about jQuery source == on window

Tags: javascript, jquery, equals, type-coercion

```
data: function( elem, name, data ) {
    if ( !jQuery.acceptData( elem ) ) {
        return;
    }
    elem = elem == window ? windowData : elem;
```

Copied directly from the jQuery source.

Why is it not safe to use `elem === window`?

Why does jQuery use type coercion on the `window` object?

It would appear that in IE there's an issue with [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.top)

```
top == window // true
top === window // false
```

Comment: Does their documentation claim it is not safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4850978/320399) for why checking againts the window object with `===` is unsafe in IE.

I think the root cause is that IE is closely coupled with the Windows OS so you have various OS objects referenced through `window` and the equality check just dies. That and it just doesn't handled the global `host` object correctly.