# IE Bug (window === top) === false

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

In IE.

```
window === top; // false
window === window.window // false
window == top; // true
window == window.window // true
```

In FF3.6 & Chrome stable this doesn't happen.

In IE `typeof`, `.toString`, `Object.prototype.toString.call` all return the same for both `top` & `window`

This is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847024/question-about-jquery-source-on-window).

Can anyone tell me why IE can't do strict equivelance?

Note that circular reference doesn't cause issues in both IE & Chrome.

```
o = {};
o.o = o;
o === o.o; // true
```

Turns out

```
window.window === window.top; // true
window.window === window.self; // true
```

So it's an issue with getting `window` on it's own.

```
for (var i in window) {
    if (window.window[i] !== window[i]) {
        console.log(i); // external, frames, clipboardData
    }
}
```

[Edit]

This is just getting stupid now:

```
 window.frames === window.frames; // false
 window.frames == window.frames; // false
 window.external == window.external; // true
 window.external === window.external; // false
 window.clipboardData === window.clipboardData; // false
 window.clipboardData == window.clipboardData; // false
```

[Further edit]

turns out that window.frames holds a pointer to the ie debugger. So having the debugger open changes the `window` object. I have to do some more testing.

```
window.frames.location === window.frames.location; // false
window.frames.location == window.frames.location; // true
window.frames.event.boundElements == window.frames.event.boundElements; // false
```

Not to mention that `window.external` just does not play nicely

```
>>for (var i in window.external) alert(i);
"Object doesn't support this action"
```

Comment: Just another artefact of the odd way that IE works. Unlikely to be fixed except in IE9+ I'm afraid.

Comment: @IainBallard is there any logical reason why IE does this or is it simply a bug?

Comment: Is it strictly speaking a bug? Seems to me that it is more a feature, and why do you ever need to compare `window === top`? I understand that you want to, be is it an actual need when `==` will do just fine?

Comment: @MartinJespersen `==` is type coercion. Type coercion is as bad as `eval`. It should always be avoided.

Comment: @Raynos: No, type coercion is something that happens and needs to be understood but is not evil. It's nothing like `eval`, which has security implications. Also, when it comes to host objects like `window` the normal rules do not apply.

Comment: @Raynos: Eval & type coercion are not bad, they are awesome. Both, however, are like guns, if you don't know what you are doing you shouldn't be playing with them, where as they are useful tools for others. In this case, figuring out if two object which represent the global scope, are the same, where there are less chance of a false positive/negative, than winning the lotto, and where the performance difference doesn't matter using it is good, especially when there is no standard anywhere that describes strict equivalence as being the way to go.

Comment: @TimDown I expect `window` to behave nicely.

Comment: @MartinJesperson I disagree. apart from the well known JSON exception, loading external javascript and other very rare cases `eval` is evil. As for type coercion, it's a major cause of bugs and should be avoided. There is nothing wrong with `implied type coercion` in using the `if` statement though. `===` & `if` are fine. `==` is bad.

Comment: @Raynos: Too sweeping. There's nothing wrong with `==` so long as you understand what it does. For example, `typeof` checks: `typeof foo == "undefined"` is perfectly safe, since both operands are guaranteed to be strings.

Comment: @TimDown if both operands are garantueed to be strings why don't you use `===`

Comment: @Raynos: In that particular case, it makes precisely no difference whether you use `===` or `==`. Why prefer `===`?

Comment: @Raynos -- Yes, IE has a bit of a funny object model; Quite a few bits of the DOM are Windows "COM" objects that are part of the core OS, and so it's not a pure DOM/Javascript system like most other browsers. It tends to make funny things like this happen. Mostly an artifact of how old IE is now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This isn't exactly a bug: host objects can do whatever they like, and the `window` object is a particularly complicated beast, serving the dual purposes of being the object that represents the browser window and also being an alias for the global object. I'd chalk this one up as a weirdness and avoid using the strict `===` operator when comparing `Window` objects.

Note that this isn't a "JavaScript is weird" shrugpost. As well as serving as the global object, `window` is a host object and pre-HTML5 could legitimately (according to spec, at least) behave however it liked. Older versions of IE take advantage of this freedom and exhibit much quirky behaviour for which there is no specification whatsoever. Trying to understand it all without access to the source code is a pointless exercise.

Comment: See edited question. It seems to be a difference between getting a property of `window` which is a DOMWindow & getting `window` itself.

Comment: @Raynos: Interesting but probably not desperately useful: using `==` causes no problems.

Comment: I found the root cause which is that `frames` and `clipboardData` don't behave nicely.

Comment: @Raynos: Really? Do you have a link for that?

Comment: check the updated question or just try it in the IE console. I just did.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who encounters this problem and needs a solution:

I ran into this problem while developing a Facebook app. I wanted to make sure the app had been loaded into the Canvas Page iframe, but in Internet Explorer `window === top` always returns false.

This:

```
window.top === window.self
```

should work in all versions of IE (and other browsers). It's great for determining if you've been framed, and it's happy, well-formed JS that won't make you feel dirty. It works inside an iframe without throwing any security warnings, too.

Answer (score 3):

[wtfjs](http://wtfjs.com) is one of my favourite sites for the really wacky oddities you can find in Javascript.

Unsurprisingly, this little IE feature has got a mention, along with an attempt at an explanation: http://wtfjs.com/2010/02/25/ie-scope

Whether that explanation is accurate or not, I can't say, but the effect has been noted before.

So yes, there may be a quirk in IE's DOM here.

But it wouldn't be the only quirk in IE, and it strikes me as being one of the less important ones. In fact, to be honest, why do this even matter? Other than having a laugh at IE's expense, what is the use-case for ever wanting to compare `window === top` in a real-world script?

Comment: comparing window objects is useful. just search for `elem == window` in jQuery. We're talking about two equivelant window objects not behaving with `===`.

Comment: @Raynos - comparing an unknown object `elem` with `window`: yes, I can see the case for that. But comparing two known objects `top` and `window`? No, I don't see why a real-world script would need this? The whole point of the question is that you already know that they should always be identical without having to check. And the fact that they're not actually identical in IE means that it's a moot point.

Comment: The explanation on wtfjs is rubbish. `toString()` is not neccessarily called when comparing objects using `==`. That only happens if one operand is a string and the other is not.

Comment: it's a specific example illustrating the bug that causes my code which uses `elem === window` to break. I want to use `===`.

Comment: @Tim Down - re 'complete rubbish': heh. Yeah, I suspected as much; it didn't sound particularly plausible. I don't have any other sensible explanation though other than simply "yes, IE has quirks". ;-)

Comment: @Spudley comparing `top` and `window` is useful to prevent being iframed.  `if(window!==top)top.location.href = window.location.href`

Answer (score -3):

`window` tends to be the global object, rather than the page. `window.window` would be a property of that global object called "window" so in theory they should never be identical (`===`) but may be similar (`==`) since that global object is in the global scope.

I haven't tested this, but as a guess, you may have better luck comparing `self` (the current page) and `parent`

Comment: -1 `window.window === window` should be true. It's a circular reference. Every reference to `window` goes "Can't find var window so I will look it up on window and returns `window.window`"

Comment: This answer is guesswork and at least partly wrong: `window` is both JavaScript global object and host object representing the window. That much is certain. Also, circular references are perfectly valid in JavaScript, so there's no reason why `window.window` couldn't be the same object as `window`.

Comment: @Raynos: That doesn't follow, since `window` is a host object.

Comment: +1 for a bad downvote. This answer is as good as any you will get. There is no standard that describes this situation since window is not an object as such but a object like representation of the global scope. Anything much more specific than this will probably require somebody who worked in the js engine at microsoft.

Comment: @Martin: No, this is not a good answer. Did you read my comment? What is an "object like representation of the global scope"? And `window` **is** an object.

Comment: @MartinJespersen your probably right. There really aught to be a seperation between the `window` DOMWindow object and the `window` global scope object.

Comment: @Raynos: I agree it would be better if there were separate global and window objects. However, this will not happen, and `Window` objects are part of HTML5: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-window-object