# this keyword problem in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>
<script>
(function(){
    var myLib = function (selector) {
        console.log(this);
        if(this === window) {
            console.log('first if statement executed');
            console.log(this);
            return new myLib(selector);
        }
        if(this.window === window){
            console.log('second if statement executed');
            console.log(this);
            return new myLib(selector);
        }
    };

    //expose myLib to the global window object
    window.myLib = myLib;
})();

myLib('.someclass')

</script>
```

**In Firefox, this is what gets logged to the console:**
Window
first if statement executed
Object {}

**In IE8, this is what gets logged to the console:**
Window
second if statement executed 
Window 
Object {}

Why does *this* not point to the window in IE when myLib is invoked, but instead *this.window* points to the window?

Comment: Short version: IE is weird about `window`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window` is weird. It's both the `window` object and the global scope object.

Since `window` is the [[Global Context]] then this works:

```
var o = 5;
window.o === 5; // true
```

Since `window` is a global variable then `window.window === window`

The fact that in IE8 `window !== this` is because IE8 hates you. IE8 really messed up the way it implemented `window` as global context and as a global variable.

To solve your code problem change

`window.myLib = myLib;`

to

```
window.myLib = function() {
    return new myLib();
};
```

Comment: Funny, I was just going to link to your prior question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850978/

Comment: @MattBall In that question I didn't particularly check `window === this`

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about IE's different implementation of window.

Answer (score 1):

if you're trying to avoid calling myLib without invoking a constructor function you can do something like this:

```
function myLib(){
  if(!(this instanceof myLib)){
    return new myLib();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will just use this instead of checking what this points to, seeing that IE's implementation of window and what this points to is different than other browsers.