# Stack Overflow in IE recursion -> window.frames not equal to itself

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, recursion, stack-overflow

I'm doing a recursion through the whole tree of javascript objects available from the window global scope.

Its all fine and dandy in Chrome, Firefox and Safari but I'm having a bit of a problem in Internet Explorer.

Basically I'm building a stack of objects as I traverse through the tree, so I can check down the line of an object has been asigned in more than one place. For example I check.

```
var ignoreStack = [window, document]; // grows over time to contain every object

ignoreStack.contains = function(obj) {
  for(var i=0;i<this.length;i++) {
    if (this[i] === obj) {return true;} 
  }
  return false;
};

// ... further down the line inside a recursion
if (!(obj instanceof Object)) {return;}
for (var prop in obj) { 
  if (ignoreStack.contains(obj[prop])) {return;}
  ignoreStack.push(obj[prop]);
  recurse(obj[prop], prop);
}
```

Now the only problem is when it checks the following:

```
// Returns true in Chrome, Safari and Firefox
console.log(window.frames.frames === window.frames);
// Return false in IE
```

Every other object in the tree is equal to itself, however `window.frames` in IE seems to be the only exception where its not true to itself, so the recursion continues on as follows:

```
// window.frames.frames.frames.frames.frames ...etc
```

Does anyone have any idea why `window.frames` is not equal to itself?

I've tried doing some digging in google and debugging using IE Developer tools, all I can gather is that its an object of type `DispHTMLWindow2` (not that that means much to me) and that (unlike in other browsers) its neither an Object nor an Array.

```
// Returns true in Chrome, Safari and Firefox
console.log(window.frames instanceof Object);
// Return false in IE
```

If somebody could shed some light on the reason why `window.frames` in IE behaves unlike any other javascript object (causing this type of infinite recursion) that would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suppose that it is most likely that there has been no correct equals operation for that particular itemtype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Related question about other host objects that are not equal in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850978/ie-bug-window-top-false)

> If somebody could shed some light on the reason why window.frames in IE behaves unlike any other javascript object (causing this type of infinite recursion) that would be much appreciated.

`window.frames` is a host object. Host objects are allowed to do whatever they please in ES3. IE is notorious for having highly misbehaving host objects. There is little you can do about it.

I recommend you do the dirty hack which is a hard coded check for whether the key is `'frames'` and the obj is `window` and ignoring the entire thing.

There are another bunch of properties inside `window.frames` that also don't behave.

Comment: +1 for ref to Host Objects (ES3 4.3.8), I had the ECMA 'bible' open at the time I was writing this piece of code but I had never even heard of Host Objects.

Comment: for reference, this is what I meant in my comment on the OP about not having a proper equals method written. I assumed the fact that it was a Host object was understood in the light of the question being asked.

Comment: @jcolebrand I don't think its about a "proper equals". I think the problem is that `window.frames` simply returns a unique object on every get for some unknown reason (IE bug?)

Comment: @raynos Im thinking value type / ref type kinda situation, but too tired to test it now..

Comment: @StevendeSalas I don't think you can test it, considering.

Comment: @Raynos ah, what an interesting device.