# window.event !== window.event in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

**Code：**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('btn1').onclick = function(){   
      if (window === window)  
        alert('window === window')
      else
        alert('window !== window');

      if (window.event === window.event)  
        alert('window.event === window.event')
      else
        alert('window.event !== window.event' );   
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="btn1" >click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**Result:**

IE(i have tested IE6 - IE8) says:

```
window === window
window.event !== window.event
```

All other browsers say:

```
window === window
window.event === window.event
```

What's the reason for IE's response? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's `NaN`?  Or a race condition?  Is this repeatable? Console dot log the value of `window.event` a few times. :)

Comment: Note that in (at least some) non-IE browsers `window.event` would likely be `undefined`. And `undefined===undefined` is true.

Answer (score 7):

I did some experimenting. It looks like every time you access `window.event` in IE, you get a new object:

```
document.body.onclick = function() {
    var u = window.event, v = window.event;
    console.log(window.event == window.event); // false
    console.log(u == v); // false
    console.log(u == u); // true
    console.log(v == v); // true
    console.log(u == window.event); // false
    console.log(v == window.event); // false
};
```

So whenever you retrieve `window.event`, IE creates a new object. If you test that object against itself (`u == u` or `v == v`) it is `true`. If you test it against another `window.event` object, it's false.

(Note that this is different behavior from `NaN`, as `var a = NaN; console.log(a == a);` is `false`.)

Think of `window.event` as something like a generator, more like `window.createCopyOfLastEvent()` in IE.  `window.event` is a getter which always returns a new object.  The following illustrates this point:

```
document.body.onclick = function() {
    var v = window.event;
    v.a = 1;
    console.log(v.a); // 1
    console.log(window.event.a); // undefined
};
```

In the above example, `window.event.a` is `undefined` when it is logged because it refers to a different object, than the one where `a = 1`.

To further illustrate, this behavior could be recreated in pure JavaScript (in a ES5 supported browser: IE9, or latest versions of FF, Chrome, or Safari):

```
var weirdObject = Object.create({ }, {
    whoa: {
        get: function() {
            return new Object();
        }
    }
});

console.log(weirdObject.whoa == weirdObject.whoa); // false
```

Or maybe even stranger looking:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'ahh', {
    get: function() {
        return Math.random();
    }
});

console.log(ahh == ahh); // false
```

Comment: it seems the reason and that experiment discovers how IE works on this issue.

Comment: That is some great detective work there.  Too bad I only have one upvote for you.

Answer (score 3):

Update:
Read this: [IE Bug (window === top) === false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850978/ie-bug-window-top-false)

In short -- IE is broken and doesn't compare host objects well.

Not all browsers support `window.event`.  Most use an `event` object passed to the function.  (`window.event` was considered an IE specific thing, though it appears that Chrome has copied it.)

Try this:

```
 document.getElementById('btn1').onclick = function(event){   
  if (!event) {event = window.event;}

  alert([typeof event, typeof window.event])

  if (window === window)  
    alert('window === window')
  else
    alert('window !== window');

  if (window.event === window.event)  
    alert('window.event === window.event')
  else
    alert('window.event !== window.event' );   
}
```

}

Comment: Ah, thanks @Blender -- I keep forgetting about Chrome doing that.

Comment: This doesn't explain why `window.event` is not equal to `window.event`.

Comment: @NathanWall -- Found a discussion that explains more.  Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The comparison behaviour is [ECMAScript-compliant](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.9.6) When the code is executed in a browser that does not support `window.event`, we're effectively comparing two undefined values which returns `true`. On MSIE `window.event` is merely a `MSEventObj` interface, meaning that two different calls to it will *not* return the same object, and they will compare falsely.

That means that, well, `window.event` will never be the same so the comparison is pointless. If you're trying to compare event types, you can do duck type comparison by forcing string comparison:

```
//false, you're either comparing undefined values or different objects
console.log(window.event == window.event);

//true, you're either comparing two "undefined" or "[object MSEventObj]" strings
console.log((""+window.event) === (""+window.event));
```

I'm not aware of a practical scenario where you would be required to perform this particular check. Determining the event type should be done by checking its `type` property:

```
function doSomething(e) {
  if (!e) var e = window.event;
  alert(e.type);//or whatever
}
```

Note that this should be executed from a script that's part of DOM - not from developer tools' console:

[image: don't]

[Overview of cross-browser event properties' quirks](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html)

Comment: +1 but it would seem that the MSIE event model is not consistent with the [W3C Events spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/) which talks about *event objects* propagating through the document. So a reference to an event object at any particular current event target should be the same object as the event object at any other current event target in any phase.