# IE top!==this(window)

Tags: javascript, iframe

To prevent iframing, I added this code in the top scope (which means `this==window`):

```
if(top!==this)top.location.search="?removeFrame"
```

this works perfectly in all browsers other than IE(failed in IE 8, keeps refreshing, not sure whether it works in later versions), I think this is because IE doesn't consider `top==this` even the main window is at the top

How to rewrite this code to make it compatible with IE?

Comment: perhaps IE8 doesn`t define `top`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try changing:

```
if(top!==this)top.location.search="?removeFrame"
```

to

```
if(top!=this)top.location.search="?removeFrame"
```

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4851112/350858) post , we should avoid using strict `(===)` operator when comparing window objects

Comment: Any explanation as to why this should be correct or at least a demonstration?