# Why does this jQuery code not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, match

Why doesn't the following jQuery code work?

```
$(function() {
    var regex = /\?fb=[0-9]+/g;
    var input = window.location.href;

    var scrape = input.match(regex); // returns ?fb=4

    var numeral = /\?fb=/g;

    scrape.replace(numeral,'');
    alert(scrape); // Should alert the number?
});
```

Basically I have a link like this:

```
http://foo.com/?fb=4
```

How do I first locate the `?fb=4` and then retrieve the number only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using the following code instead:

```
$(function() {
    var matches = window.location.href.match(/\?fb=([0-9]+)/i);

    if (matches) {
        var number = matches[1];
        alert(number); // will alert 4!
    }
});
```

Test an example of it here: http://jsfiddle.net/GLAXS/

The regular expression is only slightly modified from what you provided. The `g`lobal flag was removed, as you're not going to have multiple `fb=`'s to match (otherwise your URL will be invalid!). The case `i`nsensitive flag flag was added to match `FB=` as well as `fb=`.

The number is wrapped in curly brackets to denote a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) which is the magic which allows us to use `match`.

If [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) matches the regular expression we specify, it'll return the matched string in the first array element. The remaining elements contain the value of each capturing group we define.

In our running example, the string "?fb=4" is matched and so is the first value of the returned array. The only capturing group we have defined is the number matcher; which is why `4` is contained in the second element.

Comment: Thanks, care to explain how this works exactly? What's that array on the matches?

Comment: An even better way would be to search on `window.location.search` so you don't accidentally match substrings in the path or in the hash.

Comment: `match` returns an array of matches.

Comment: @tfbox the parenthesis in `/\?fb=([0-9]+)/i` create a "capturing group".  The substring that matches the pattern of that capturing group is available in the array that String.match() returns.  Index 0 is the entire matched string, and 1..N are the substrings that matched each capturing group.

Answer (score 4):

If you all you need is to grab the value of `fb`, just use capturing parenthesis:

```
    var regex = /\?fb=([0-9]+)/g; 
    var input = window.location.href;

    var tokens = regex.exec(input);

    if (tokens) { // there's a match
        alert(tokens[1]); // grab first captured token
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using the [following function](http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/JavaScript-QueryString-ParseGet-QueryString-with-Client-Side-JavaScript.aspx) to read the query string parameter in JavaScript:

```
function getQuerystring(key, default_) {
    if (default_==null)
        default_="";
    key = key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+key+"=([^&#]*)");
    var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if(qs == null)
        return default_;
    else
        return qs[1];
}
```

and then:

```
alert(getQuerystring('fb'));
```

Comment: I'm seriously new to regex, only got my fingers dirty with it today so looking at that code there I have no idea how to implement it at all lol.

Answer (score 2):

So, you want to feed a querystring and then get its value based on parameters?

---

I had had half a mind to offer *[Get query string values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115)*.

But then I saw [a small kid abusing a much respectful Stack Overflow answer](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/bujs-1-getparameterbyname/).

```
// Revised, cooler.
function getParameterByName(name) {
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)')
                    .exec(window.location.search);
    return match ?
        decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '))
        : null;
}
```

And while you are at it, just call the function like this.

```
getParameterByName("fb")
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are new to Regex, why not try [Program that illustrates the ins and outs of Regular Expressions](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm)

Comment: JSLint doesn't handle jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505251/what-good-is-jslint-if-jquery-fails-the-validation

Comment: Thanks Ben, I didn't know that actually. I will use these resources from now on before I answer.

Comment: I partially lied... turns out if you are running Lint locally, jQuery core will actually pass Lint:
http://docs.jquery.com/JQuery_Core_Style_Guidelines#JSLint